# SharePoint 2010 - Configure People Picker columns (add/remove)

Tags: 2010, people-picker, people-search

How it is possible to configure the Sharepoint 2010 People Picker?
I want ot remove the column [Mobile Number] and add a column with the normal Phone Number.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1):

It depends on authentication mode you are using.

AFAIK for classic-mode authentication there is no option to set columns displayed on people picker list view (disclaimer: I never had need to dig in deep in this issue since most of my projects uses claim based auth - so maybe there is way but it is nothing obvious and simple)

For Claims-based authentication you can write your own custom claim provider.

Resource: [People Picker overview (SharePoint Server 2010)](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg602068.aspx#auth)

> **Claims-based authentication**
>
> You can write a custom claims provider to
>   control what information is displayed and what results are returned in
>   response to a query from the People Picker control.

An you can find all info needed to write own custom claims provider on blog post series by Steve Peschka. Part 3 is 'people picker related':

[Writing a Custom Claims Provider for SharePoint 2010 - Part 3: Searching Claims](http://blogs.technet.com/b/speschka/archive/2010/03/13/writing-a-custom-claims-provider-for-sharepoint-2010-part-3-searching-claims.aspx)