# How to Modify / Create Custom People Editor Dialog ?

Tags: people-picker

I want to Modify the Default People picker properties as Shown below. I want to hide the Highlighted Columns in the below image.

Does anybody know how can I do this using C#?

I can modify it or do I have to create new one?

[image: People picker pop-up]

Answer (score 2):

I use the folowing to create my custom dialog in C#:

Try to override constructor of PickerDialog class

For example:

```
public class CustomPickerDialog : PickerDialog
{
    public CustomPickerDialog()
        : base(new SimpleQueryControl(), new TableResultControl(), new CustomPeopleEditor())
    {
        ArrayList columnDisplayNames = ((TableResultControl)base.ResultControl).ColumnDisplayNames;
        columnDisplayNames.Clear();
        columnDisplayNames.Add("Name");
        columnDisplayNames.Add("LoginName");
        columnDisplayNames.Add("Email");
        ArrayList columnNames = ((TableResultControl)base.ResultControl).ColumnNames;
        columnNames.Clear();
        columnNames.Add("Name");
        columnNames.Add("LoginName");
        columnNames.Add("Email");
        ArrayList columnWidths = ((TableResultControl)base.ResultControl).ColumnWidths;
        columnWidths.Clear();
        columnWidths.Add("40%");
        columnWidths.Add("30%");
        columnWidths.Add("30%");
    }
}
```

Next override OnInit method in PickerEditor class:

```
public class CustomPeopleEditor: PeopleEditor
{
    protected override void OnInit(EventArgs e)
    {
        base.OnInit(e);
        PickerDialogType = typeof(CustomPickerDialog);
    }
}
```

In this example there are u'll see only 3 fields in people dialog.
By this way you can create custom  people dialog. 
**And don't forget to add your custom control to "safecontrols" in web.config of web application**

Answer (score 0):

No idea about doing it with Object Model (C#) but you can remove the setting for a People Picker property by specifying the property name you want to clear, and using empty quotation marks for the property value.

To remove a property setting from People Picker, type the following command:

```
stsadm.exe -o setproperty -pn <Property Name> -pv "" -url <Web application URL>
```

For more information, see Peoplepicker-searchadforests: Stsadm property http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc263460(office.12).aspx

Note: This is applicable to SharePoint 2010

Answer (score 0):

Can you confirm that you can actually hide a column (like email/phone) from the People Picker search results using the setproperty stsadm command?

Because TechNet specifies that the *set-property* command is used for changing settings of the people picker control, and doesn't mention the hiding of specific fields.

> You can remove the **setting** for a People Picker property by specifying
>   the property name you want to clear, and using empty quotation marks
>   for the property value.
>
> To remove a property setting from People Picker, type the following
>   command: stsadm.exe -o setproperty -pn-pv "" -url
>   http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg602066.aspx#section1

I've got two questions:

Does this *set-property* command actually works for removing fields from the people picker?

What are the property names for the values that you can remove?

If this solution works, this guy is wrong ;)
[SharePoint 2010 - Configure People Picker columns (add/remove)](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/37346/sharepoint-2010-configure-people-picker-columns-add-remove)

Thanks in advance,
Bastiaan